# How do I convince Eclipse to show javadoc documentation under Ubuntu 9.04 for openjdk?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, javadoc

I'm having a pretty hard time with this!

I have installed the java documentation at:

> file:///usr/share/doc/openjdk-6-jre/api/index.html

And loading that file up does show me all the documentation.

However, I would like to browse it directly from within eclipse and see the documentation when I hover over a class. For example, when I hover over "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest", I would like to see the documentation for it. All I get is:

> Note: This element has no attached
>   source and the Javadoc could not be
>   found in the attached Javadoc.

Can anyone help correct my dev environment?

Comment: Instead of installing the Servlet API documentation locally, you can also point Eclipse to `http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/` in the properties for `servlet-api.jar`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Java API Javadocs to show up in Eclipse in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678278/how-to-get-java-api-javadocs-to-show-up-in-eclipse-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` is not part of the OpenJDK, and so the OpenJDK documentation would not contain information on it.

You need to install the [Servlet API](http://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr154/) documentation instead, then, in the library section of your Package Explorer tab, right-click `servlet-api.jar`, and select Properties. You will then be able to select a javadoc location for that.

Alternatively, for an Ubuntu-friendly solution, install the `libservlet2.5-java-doc` package, then add the javadoc to your Servlet API jar file using the procedure above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will give this a go later when I am on that machine. I prefer to let ubuntu manage as much as possible so that part of the answer is ideal!

Comment: I still got an error initially but forgot to add file: before the uri. Incidentally, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest was not being used from OpenJDK, it was (in google app engine) in a package called geronimo which google use for their servlets. Apparently, "Geronimo is a Java EE 1.4 certified app server" which means that I can use the docs you mentioned anyway as it offers the same API.

Answer (score 2):

Under Properties, you can enter a URL that hosts the servlet API, such as:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure will enable Java documentation to be available in Eclipse when you hover over some Java class.
Download the Java Documentation (this is for version 6) from
http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=4&ved=0CC0QFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcds.sun.com%2Fis-bin%2FINTERSHOP.enfinity%2FWFS%2FCDS-CDS_Developer-Site%2Fen_US%2F-%2FUSD%2FViewProductDetail-Start%3FProductRef%3Djdk-6u10-docs-oth-JPR%40CDS-CDS_Developer&ei=T-z3S87CAYuyNq3UweAF&usg=AFQjCNH54wkg50p7PJGmv6dEJd0zxXTGRA&sig2=Pv8-OZ7ZQEAsh89kUFhvUw
This is a zipped file jdk-*-docs.zip ( * indicates the version number, for e.g., 6u18 which implies Java Version 6.18).
Open Eclipse. Click on Window > Show View > Javadoc
Right click on the Javadoc console. Select Open Input. Click "Change Attached Source". Select "External File". Navigate to the directory in which jdk-*-docs.zip exists. Open it. And there you have it - the entire documentation available to you at your fingertip(mousetip?).

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different method is needed for Android projects in Eclipse, where you specify the JavaDoc location in **"Java Build Path"**, rather than **"JavaDoc Location"** settings. See the answer here, which worked for me:

[Problems with javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980002/problems-with-javadoc)

(The JavaDoc problem started happening to me when I deleted my old Android SDK folder.)