# Problems with javadoc

Tags: android, eclipse

When I start a new android project and use native android methods and components and java methods and components, I can't read their description because javadoc send me this message:

***Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.***

I have the latest android documentation in my android-sdk folder and javadoc works when I work with standard java projects, but not with android project. Have you got any ideas why does it happen and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found solution myself. In this situation you need to correct a path of your javadoc at ***Project->Properties->Java Build path->AndroidX.X(where X.X is platform version)->android.jar->Javadoc location***.

It should be pointed at your docs\reference location

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse (you should mention the IDE) you should get a button to "attach source" when you get that message. Just click that button and point it to the docs directory on your computer or on the internet and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, I use eclipse, but when this message appears there is no any button like "attach source". When I set focus at this message there are only "Show in javadoc view", "open declaration" and "open external javadoc" buttons

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the following url & try to implement the instructions provided

**http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/01/browsing-android-source-in-eclipse/**

Comment: It's really interesting, but not what I need. I can't look through a method's description, but not through a class description.